# One of my flages is marked as "Disputed". What does this mean?

Tags: discussion, flagging, flags

I have flaged one [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789131/access-camera-from-terminal-ssh-on-ubuntu-touch-15-04) as "low quality" during a review. Today I saw that the flag was marked as *Disputed*. What does this mean?

P.S. I have marked it as low quality because I think that the author could have done better without much trouble.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag.